# PHP header issue in Location

Tags: php

Unable to redirect a link using header in php, used the following code

```
header('Location: http://x.in/home/index.php');
```

Getting the following message in console

> Reload the page to get source for:....

Comment: uh, php error messages usually don't appear in the console, never heard of that before, they should just be displayed directly on the page. are you sure your looking the right place? turned on `error_reporting`?

Comment: Is this after the page has started producing output? Header only works if performed before any html is output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Sorry that is a response  in  firebug net